# Set resize of XUL panel to auto

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an add on for Firefox on the Addon SDK (v.1.11).

My addon uses a toolbar button to display a XUL panel. This panel contains buttons that dynamically (using [jQuery's slideToggle(500)](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)) expand / collapse divs, modifying the overall dimensions of the panel.

**Problem**

The resizing is done smoothly, and the containing HTML elements are resized automatically since their height/width is set to 'auto'. However, the panel itself does not take height/width 'auto' values, only integers. This forces me to manually call a function to resize the panel when a collapse/expand motion has finished. This creates a very unpleasant effect. Is there a way to allow the panel to resize to its content automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The system isn't ideal right now so I've been connecting the content and panel via a `resize` port event that handles the auto-resize of the panel.  Here's how it works.

In your Panel or main.js code listen for `resize` events.

```
Panel.port.on("resize", function (sizes) {
  Panel.resize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
});
```

Then in your Content Panel code use something like the following (when the DOM is ready):

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
   self.port.emit("resize", { "width" :  $("body").width(),
                              "height" : $("body").height() });
});
```

This will send a `resize` event through the panel ports system every time you content window size changes from an expand or collapse.

**(update)**

If you're not getting a `$(window).resize()` event from your DOM then you'll have to hook something up more manual to your slideToggle function.  Try hooking up a callback function to every slideToggle call you make.  Here's an example:

```
function emitResize() {
       self.port.emit("resize", { "width" :  $("body").width(),
                                  "height" : $("body").height() });

}

$('#yourid').slideToggle('fast', emitResize);
```

This will trigger the resize event after every slideToggle animation when the size of your page has finished changign.  You might want to alter the `$("body").width()` and `$("body").height()` calls to use a containing div if you've set a static width or height for your document.

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work because I believe it has the same problems my code has. The resize event on the window does not get triggered because I am actually expanding / collapsing elements in the body, which do not modify the size of the window because it has a static height / width (and cannot be set to auto).

Comment: If the window doesn't trigger a resize at all then you'll want to use a custom callback function to your slideToggle.  I'll add an example to it above.